# Method to update users role is giving an error when using Collection2 package

Tags: meteor

Here is my method:

```
removeRole: function(role) {
check(role, String);
    var user = Meteor.user();
if (!user || ! AccountsAdmin.checkForAdminAuthentication(user))
  throw new Meteor.Error(401, "You need to be an authenticated admin");

    // handle non-existing role
    if (Meteor.roles.find({name: role}).count() < 1 )
        throw new Meteor.Error(422, 'Role ' + role + ' does not exist.');

    if (role === 'admin')
        throw new Meteor.Error(422, 'Cannot delete role admin');

    // remove the role from all users who currently have the role
    // if successfull remove the role
    Meteor.users.update(
        {roles: role },
        {$pull: {roles: role }},
        {multi: true},
        function(error) {
            if (error) {
                throw new Meteor.Error(422, error);
            } else {
                Roles.deleteRole(role);
            }
        }
    );
},
```

Here is the error I receive when looking at the call in Kadira:

```
message: After filtering out keys not in the schema, your modifier is now empty 
stack:
Error: After filtering out keys not in the schema, your modifier is now empty
    at [object Object].doValidate (packages/aldeed_collection2-core/lib/collection2.js:282:1)
    at [object Object]._.each.Mongo.Collection.(anonymous function) [as update] (packages/aldeed_collection2-core/lib/collection2.js:83:1)
    at [object Object].Meteor.methods.removeRole (packages/accounts-admin-ui-bootstrap-3/server/methods.js:86:1)
```

Line 86 of that methods.js is "Meteor.users.update" in the code above. When trying to debug this using breakpoints it appears this is where the error is happening as well.

I am using [this package](https://github.com/andylash/meteor-accounts-admin-ui-bootstrap-3) to help with the user management UI that I am creating, although I have did some customizing to it. I have also tested this on a different version of my project for troubleshooting and I have found that it works when I don't use the [Collection2 package](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2).

Here is my custom schema setup:

```
Schema = {};

Schema.UserProfile = new SimpleSchema({
    userProfile: {
        type: Object
    },
    'userProfile.firstName': {
        type: String,
        optional: true,
        label: "First Name"
    },
    'userProfile.lastName': {
        type: String,
        optional: true,
        label: "Last Name"
    },
    'userProfile.birthday': {
        type: Date,
        optional: true,
        label: "Date of Birth"
    },
    'userProfile.contactEmail': {
        type: String,
        optional: true,
        label: "Email"
    },     
    'userProfile.gender': {
        type: String,
        allowedValues: ['Male', 'Female'],
        optional: true,
        label: "Gender"
    },
    'userProfile.address': {
        type: String,
        optional: true,
        label: "Address"
    },
    'userProfile.city': {
        type: String,
        optional: true,
        label: "City"
    },
    'userProfile.stateProvince': {
        type: String,
        optional: true,
        label: "State/Province"
    },
    'userProfile.postalCode': {
        type: String,
        optional: true,
        label: "Postal Code"
    },
    'userProfile.phoneNumber': {
        type: String,
        optional: true,
        label: "Phone Number"
    },
    userProfilePayment: {
        type: Object
    },
    'userProfilePayment.paymentEmail': {
        type: String,
        optional: true,
        label: "Payment Email"
    },
    'userProfilePayment.address': {
        type: String,
        optional: true,
        label: "Address"
    },
    'userProfilePayment.city': {
        type: String,
        optional: true,
        label: "City"
    },
    'userProfilePayment.stateProvince': {
        type: String,
        optional: true,
        label: "State/Province"
    },
    'userProfilePayment.postalCode': {
        type: String,
        optional: true,
        label: "Postal Code"
    },
    'userProfilePayment.phoneNumber': {
        type: String,
        optional: true,
        label: "Phone Number"
    },

});

Schema.User = new SimpleSchema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        // For accounts-password, either emails or username is required, but not both. It is OK to make this
        // optional here because the accounts-password package does its own validation.
        // Third-party login packages may not require either. Adjust this schema as necessary for your usage.
        optional: true
    },
    emails: {
        type: Array,
        // For accounts-password, either emails or username is required, but not both. It is OK to make this
        // optional here because the accounts-password package does its own validation.
        // Third-party login packages may not require either. Adjust this schema as necessary for your usage.
        optional: true
    },
    "emails.$": {
        type: Object
    },
    "emails.$.address": {
        type: String,
        regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Email
    },
    "emails.$.verified": {
        type: Boolean
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date
    },
    profile: {
        type: Schema.UserProfile,
        optional: true
    },
    // Make sure this services field is in your schema if you're using any of the accounts packages
    services: {
        type: Object,
        optional: true,
        blackbox: true
    },
    // Add `roles` to your schema if you use the meteor-roles package.
    // Option 1: Object type
    // If you specify that type as Object, you must also specify the
    // `Roles.GLOBAL_GROUP` group whenever you add a user to a role.
    // Example:
    // Roles.addUsersToRoles(userId, ["admin"], Roles.GLOBAL_GROUP);
    // You can't mix and match adding with and without a group since
    // you will fail validation in some cases.
    roles: {
        type: Object,
        optional: true,
        blackbox: true
    },
    // In order to avoid an 'Exception in setInterval callback' from Meteor
    heartbeat: {
        type: Date,
        optional: true
    },
    // Added to work with mizzao:user-status
    status: {
        type: Object,
        optional: true,
        blackbox: true
    }
});

Meteor.users.attachSchema(Schema.User);

Meteor.users.allow({
    // NOTE: The client should not be allowed to add users directly!
    insert: function(userId, doc) {
        // only allow posting if you are logged in
        console.log("doc: " + doc + " userId: " + userId);
        return !! userId;
    },

    update: function(userId, doc, fieldNames) {
        // only allow updating if you are logged in
        console.log("doc: " + doc + " userId: " + userId);
        // NOTE: a user can only update his own user doc and only the 'userProfile' and 'userProfilePayment' field
        return !! userId && userId === doc._id && _.isEmpty(_.difference(fieldNames, ['userProfile, userProfilePayment'])); 
    },
    /* NOTE: The client should not generally be able to remove users
    remove: function(userID, doc) {
        //only allow deleting if you are owner
        return doc.submittedById === Meteor.userId();
    }
    */
});
```

Comment: don't know if this is the cause, but in your schema you define roles as an Object, while in your update call you seem to be treating it as an array (because of $pull)

Comment: @bluebird Thanks for the comment! I believe you are correct, thanks for noticing that. I would like to keep roles as an Object because I am using groups with the roles package, would you have any suggestion on how I can make my update call work with roles being an Object? I've tried a few things but can't seem to get it right..

Answer (score 0):

To remove a key in a mongodb update you want to use the [$unset](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/) operator:

```
Meteor.users.update({ roles: role },{ $unset: { roles: 1 }}, { multi: true })
```

It's just a bit unusual that in your model a user can only have a single role.